# What does the word "should" mean in the sentence

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

> For Mrs. Bennet, a woman's worth is determined not by what she is but by what her husband has, and it would be a great shame If any of her daughters **should** remain single.

Why the word "should" put in the sentence ? What's that means?

Comment: Replace with "were to", does that give you more insight?

Answer (score 1):

"Should" can be used to express a conditional meaning or possibility: If any of her daughters *were to* remain single, as CrossRoads says, it would be a shame.

> 3 formal (expressing the conditional mood) referring to a possible
>   event or situation.
>
> ‘if you should change your mind, I'll be at the hotel’ ‘should anyone
>   arrive late, admission is likely to be refused’

[Should (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/should)